# Ubuntu not recognized by Win7 network manager

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, samba

Until yesterday I've been successfully  connecting Ubuntu 15.04 to WIN7 through ethernet;

Win7 was sharing internet and Ubuntu has a shared-folder you could access through Win7.

But now it isn't working anymore,
From the Network manager on windows I can see that the  ethernet connection is `unidentified` but I can't seem to troubleshoot in any way;

Ubuntu network manager `auto-ethernet` option blinks but no connection is established.

I've tried configuring Samba workgroup and creating a home group on win 7 but without any success;

### edit:

if I connect through wifi network directly to router (tplink 4g router) the shared folder on ubuntu is accessible from Win (I must be something related to eth connection)

Comment: Can your machines [`ping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) each other?

Comment: @Melebius how would I find address to ping ?

Comment: The easiest way is using command line: `ipconfig` in Windows, `ifconfig` in Linux.

Comment: @Melebius I tried `ping 192.168.0.150 -c4` in ubuntu terminal but response was 'network unreachable'  (got the ping address from ipconfig on win)

Comment: I had also tried running nmap before that but I couldn't find anything ( `nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/16` )

Comment: Still too little information. Has your Ubuntu machine a valid IP address too? Are the computers connected with a single cable or using some networking device (switch, router)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29151/discussion-between-user2417031-and-melebius).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved with the folowing steps:

1. Stop Network Manager `/etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop`
2. Remove the Service from Run Levels `update-rc.d -f NetworkManager remove`
3. Edit your interfaces file `vi /etc/network/interfaces`

---

When you are editting the network interface you can set you inteface as

**Interface with DHCP**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

or as **Static Interface**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address x.x.x.x
  gateway x.x.x.y
  netmask x.x.x.x
  network x.x.x.z
  broadcast x.x.x.n
```

and save `vi /etc/network/interfaces` then do the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

if you set a static addressing you must to be sure you have set DNS.

edit the following file `vi /etc/resolv.conf`

```
search example.com
domain example.com
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

set your desired DNS server and save.

and there you have your network interface working again.

---

Aditional Resources. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic)

Comment: on `/etc/init.d/networking restart` it responds `stop: job failed while stopping:networking  ─ start: already running `

Comment: rebooting the system hangs checking for network-manager - after a while  it goes on `booting system without network configuration`, reading the resource you linked to I realized my version uses upstart